# Codeigniter ajax information needed 

Tags: codeigniter

I am a beginner with Codeigniter. This will be my first time to use Ajax. I want only  "content" part change when I click the navigation links. I need to learn how to use ajax in my site.

MY_Controller.php :

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {

  protected $data = array();

  function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
  }

   function render_page($view) {
    if( ! $this->input->is_ajax_request() )
    {
      //do this to don't repeat in all controllers...
      $this->load->view('templates/header', $this->data);
      //menu_data must contain the structure of the menu...
      //you can populate it from database or helper
    }

    $this->load->view($view, $this->data);

    if( ! $this->input->is_ajax_request() )
    {
     $this->load->view('templates/menu');
     $this->load->view('templates/footer', $this->data);
    }
  }
```

My home/about controller view function:

```
    public function view($page = 'home')
    {
     $this->load->helper('text');
        $this->data['records']= $this->services_model->getAll();
        if ( ! file_exists('application/views/pages/'.$page.'.php'))
        {
            // Whoops, we don't have a page for that!
            show_404();
        }

        $data['title'] = ucfirst($page); // Capitalize the first letter


        $this->render_page('pages/'.$page,$data);


    }
```

I think , I could enable ajax in MY_Controller.php. What to do after this? How shall i enable posts in the view?

Edit : I made some more research about jquery and ajax. 
This is my navigation menu part of html :

```
    <div id="sidebar-content">
    <ul id="menu">
    <li class="current"><a href="<?php echo site_url('home'); ?>">ANASAYFA</a></li>
    <li><a href="<?php echo site_url('about'); ?>">HAKKIMIZDA</a></li>
......
```

I have written and ajax.js file in the head section as :

//Navigation

```
$("#sidebar-content ul li a").click( function(){     
        $.ajax({
                    url: "<?php echo site_url('about'); ?>",
                    type: 'POST';
                    data: JSON,
                    success: function(msg) {
                        $('#content').body(msg);
                    }
                });
                });

        return false;
});
```

Can you refine my code ? One more problem is :If I use the ajax in the head part,how can i post different pages as urls?

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question :S

Comment: I made more explanation. I did not use Ajax before. I am trying to understand its logic. $this->input->post('some_data'); ... how can i use it with navigation menu ?

Comment: What's the problem within your code anyway? I suppose it will work flawlessly when using AJAX. And what do you mean by `How shall I enable ajax in the view?`, I don't get what you're saying. Are you looking for jQuery code example?

Comment: When the site opens , there is an animation for loading page and after that navigation menu and content splits into each side. I want only content change when I click links. I dont know how to use it in my code. I did it in my controller but nothing changed. I need a direction to change only content.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is a little ambiguous, but here are some issues I can see with your JQuery:

- You have set `data: Json` in your JQuery, but it looks like you are
  returning HTML, so change this to HTML.
- You have a semi colon after `type: post` when it should be just a
  comma
- The url points to the controller, not the method. Change it to `"<?php echo site_url('about/view'); ?>",`
- There is no such thing as JQuery `.body()`, you want `.html()` or the complete line for your success function: `$('#content').html(msg);`. Obviosult make sure you have a element named id="content".JQuery will then replace this with the reponse from the server, which should be pure html returned from your controller. You can use codeigniters $this->load->view() to return the correct file.

Other notes - it seems you need to read up on JQuery, especially the [ajax function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Here's a good tutorial to follow about using Ajax with CI - http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/codeigniter-from-scratch-day-8-ajax/

Finally, use the console and network features in Chrome's developer tools web inspector or get Firebug for Firefox this way you can see js errors and monitor ajax requests (XHR)